# Issue with Generics

Tags: java, generics

**Code**:

```
  interface BaseIntr<T>{
      void saveSwiftMsg(Collection<String> headers) throws Exception;
  }

 class Impl implements BaseIntr{
       public void saveSwiftMsg(Collection<String> headers) throws Exception { }     
  }
```

**EDITED** version of the code:

```
  interface BaseIntr<T>{
     T process(T t);
     void saveSwiftMsg(Collection<String> headers)      throws Exception;
  }

  class Impl implements BaseIntr{
     public void saveSwiftMsg(Collection<String> headers) throws Exception {    }
    @Override
    public Object process(Object t) {       return t;   }   
  }
```

**Working Environment**:

Java version: 1.7.0_04, vendor: Oracle Corporation

Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: Cp1252

OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

The java compiler throws the following exception. But If I remove < T > from BaseIntr, it works fine.

```
javac gen\GenericsTest.java
gen\GenericsTest.java:18: error: Impl is not abstract and does not override abstract     method saveSwiftMsg(Collection) in BaseIntr
 class Impl implements BaseIntr{
 ^
 gen\GenericsTest.java:20: error: name clash: saveSwiftMsg(Collection<String>) in Impl and saveSwiftMsg(Collection<String>) in BaseIntr have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other
 public void saveSwiftMsg(Collection<String> headers) throws Exception {
                ^
2 errors
```

Comment: Why did you make the interface generic? You don't use `T` anywhere...

Comment: Make sure the Collection class is the same, as well as that the method name is the same (a char could be written in a different language).

Edit: it's strange, it couldn't be missing @Override?

Also, try parameterizing 'implements BaseIntr' with something, e.g. implements BaseIntr<Object>

Comment: @assylias, is it mandatory to use T, though without use, it hardly makes any sense.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee If you don't need the interface to be generic, don't do it! Simply declare it as `interface BaseIntr {...}`...

Comment: @assylias, I want to know the root cause of the problem with the given code. I think, Generics is not mandatory anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a generic type without specifying its type arguments (`implements BaseIntr`), you use the raw type. These are [defined](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8) by the Java Language Specification as follows:

> To facilitate interfacing with non-generic legacy code, it is possible to use as a type the erasure (§4.6) of a parameterized type (§4.5) or the erasure of an array type (§10.1) whose element type is a parameterized type. Such a type is called a raw type.
>
> More precisely, a raw type is defined to be one of:
>
> - The reference type that is formed by taking the name of a generic type declaration without an accompanying type argument list.

and

> The type of a constructor (§8.8), instance method (§8.4, §9.4), or non-static field (§8.3) M of a raw type C that is not inherited from its superclasses or superinterfaces is the raw type that corresponds to the erasure of its type in the generic declaration corresponding to C.

That is, the inherited method has signature

```
saveSwiftMsg(Collection headers) throws Exception
```

To override, the overriding method must have the same signature as the inherited one. It doesn't, resulting in the compilation error.

I strongly recommend to only ever use raw types for their intended purpose (to interface with legacy code), and to enable (and fix) the corresponding compiler warnings.

For that matter, so does the specification:

> The use of raw types is allowed only as a concession to compatibility of legacy code. The use of raw types in code written after the introduction of generics into the Java programming language is strongly discouraged. It is possible that future versions of the Java programming language will disallow the use of raw types.
>
> To make sure that potential violations of the typing rules are always flagged, some accesses to members of a raw type will result in compile-time unchecked warnings. The rules for compile-time unchecked warnings when accessing members or constructors of raw types are as follows:
>
> - At an assignment to a field: if the type of the left-hand operand is a raw type, then a compile-time unchecked warning occurs if erasure changes the field's type.
> - At an invocation of a method or constructor: if the type of the class or interface to search (§15.12.1) is a raw type, then a compile-time unchecked warning occurs if erasure changes any of the formal parameter types of the method or constructor.

You should heed that compiler warning, and specify the type parameter of the interface you implement.

Answer (score 3):

Your interface is parametrized with a Type `T` when you implement it you have to specify its type like this :

```
class Impl implements BaseIntr<String>{
}
```

That is if you want to implement it for `String`. But you can delegate the parameter to the implemenation class :

```
class Impl<T> implements BaseIntr<T>{
}
```

Then you would need to specify the type when instanciating the class.

Comment: It's not mandatory to use Generics in the child,right? I may not to use Generics in the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

you neeed to specify  in sub class also

```
class Impl implements BaseIntr<T>{
       public void saveSwiftMsg(Collection<String> headers) throws Exception { }     
  }
```

Actually you nees to specify the type.That is good like

```
interface BaseIntr<String>{
      void saveSwiftMsg(Collection<String> headers) throws Exception;
  }

 class Impl implements BaseIntr<String>{
           public void saveSwiftMsg(Collection<String> headers) throws Exception { }     
      }
```

Comment: is it illegal to implement raw List?